# Processing job v.s. training job in SageMaker

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

What is the difference between a processing job and a training job? I am running training job and did not launch processing job, why does my account have processing job running?

Answer (score 1):

Training job focuses on a process that train a model, for example it will use a PyTorch or TensorFlow container, or SageMaker built-in algorithms, or have a Hyper parameters tuning job associated with the training job. It may include an MPI cluster for distributed training. Finally it outputs a model artifact.

Processing jobs focus on pre/post processing, and have API and containers for ML data processing tools like SK-learn pipeline or Dusk/Spark.

Why do you see processing jobs - When you are [profiling a training job](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/debugger-profiling-report.html) (enabled by default), then a matching processing job is created to process the profiler report. You can [disable profiling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/debugger-turn-off-profiling.html) by adding `disable_profiler=True` parameter to the estimator object.

Generally speaking training jobs have a richer API than processing jobs, and allows more customization. The right choice will depend on your specific use case.